# Cathedral, "Кафедральный", why is ф in there?

Tags: этимология, история-языка

After reading [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C3%B6nigsberg_Cathedral) I got curious how ф is in place of "th" in English for the word Cathedral (Кафедральный)? Sounds almost like a coffee-place. (I know it is not Café or Kafee in russian but кофе so it would be кофедрала something. Ok, enough of the silliness.)

---

How is it that the word Кафедральный has this ф instead of some other Cyrillic letters?

Comment: https://russian.stackexchange.com/questions/219/are-there-words-that-can-be-spelled-with-both-%d1%82-and-%d1%84

Comment: Russian is actually the only Slavic language I can think of which has _кофе_ for coffee and not a variation of _кава_

Comment: @Quassnoi omg you are right!

Comment: How does it sound like a coffee place? Does cathedral sound like a coffee place to you too?

Comment: @Abakan russian word кофе sounds a bit similar to кафе which is first part of the russian word cathedral.

Comment: In no way is it similar!

Comment: Okay okay, sorry for being rude or whatever I accidentally did.

Comment: nothing to apologize for, maybe for a foreigner there's similarity, but they differ in the last phoneme, which is E (narrow) in кафе-дральный and Э (wide) in кафe... where the кафе- part is pronounced virtually identically to кафе-дральный is in the word кафе-терий (cafeteria)

Comment: @Abakan Кофе-дральный собор. Мне, пожалуйста, двойной эспрессо за здравие. А мне три заупокойных латте на вынос.

Comment: Sorry if my sense of humor was misplaced, I am not very religious person most days.

Comment: no, it wasn't, outside of joking about a rope in the home of a suicider, it cannot be

Comment: No I usually don't joke about such things, @БаянКупи-ка

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word **кафедра**, which is the base for **кафедральный**, in Russian is a loan word from Greek, [**καθέδρα**](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F).

Pre-reform Russian alphabet contained the Greek letter [**θ** (фита)](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0) and by the old orthograpical rules the word **кафедральный** would be spelled as [**каθедральный**](http://xn--90ax2c.xn--p1ai/catalog/000200_000018_RU_NLR_DIGIT_5820/)

As a result of the reform of 1918, by which it was abolished, among other things, it was replaced with the letter **Ф**.

But i believe **θ** was still pronounced like **Ф**, which provided  justification for such a replacement.

Nowadays however, in transliteration of the English **TH** (which is similar to the Greek **θ**) instead of **Ф** the Russian letter **T** would rather be used or **C**, depending on the position in a word.

Comment: Ah so you actually had something like a theta letter before 1918? Wow this is really interesting.

Comment: @mathreadler indeed, the old alphabet had all kinds of peculiar characters for special cases, like transliteration of Greek, or representing obsolete phonemes preserved only in writing